# Accessory for connecting a manual scissor jack to a drill to lift it faster

Tags: tools, powertools, hand-tools, adapter

I have a scissor jack and I was wondering if rather spinning it manually, if it is possible engaging it to my drill.

[image]

I'm pretty sure that there is an accessory like a hook for drills, or something similar, however I'm struggling to find it.

If there is no such accessory, maybe there is a combination of pieces which might sort my problem.

Comment: @brhans He does not say he want to make a drill press. I believe He wants to operate the jack by using a drill instead of the hand crank.

Comment: @brhans True, but reading the text of the question suggests that the title is miss worded. *"if rather spinning it manually, if it is possible engaging it to my drill."*

Comment: "Drill press" was added in an edit, I took that back out.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a clevis pin like the image, with a bit of hex shaft welded into it for the chuck to grip.

Remove the safety clip and withdraw the clevis pin to allow the jack eye-hole to pass into the jaw, then push the pin through and secure with the safety clip. A spacer to reduce the play between the clevis pin diameter and the jack eye-hole diameter will reduce excessive play and wear.

I would make a shaft to go into the drill chuck from some hexagonal shaft - commonly available and likely stronger than grinding flats on some cheap jack handle...

[image]

[image]

Comment: HOW.  **How does the hitch pin interface with the hole in the jack**.  *The best answers on this site not only provide an "answer" but the leave detailed info on how to do what the answer is saying is the thing to do*.

Comment: @AlaskaMan the pin goes through the hole - which is where the spacer I mentioned comes in - a "thick" washer if you will.... because none of the other answers addressed the excessive play which causes rapid wear.

Comment: Something is missing here. The drill will just spin the clevis pin in the hole not turn the jack screw

Comment: Yeah, I'm super confused.

Comment: I posted a YouTube video in my answer that shows  a great hack and a scissor jack in use , for anyone who is unclear on how it works.

Comment: @SolarMike Much more informative answer, *there are clevis pins available short enough to not need a spacer*. And i still think the premise is flawed as the drill will spin the pin in the hole and not turn the hole around in a circle.

Comment: @AlaskaMan why do you think I am suggesting to spin the clevis pin?  I have twice made it clear to add hex shaft which will rotate the jaw.

Comment: @SolarMike It was not clear that you wanted use the receiver hitch part, it read as though you were saying weld a hex shaft to the clevis pin.    *"I would use a clevis pin like the image, with a bit of hex shaft welded into it for the chuck to grip."*  Thus the confusion. **The added image makes it clear** that you suggest using a clevis pin WITH the receiver  part, but the wording was ( still could use some more details ) not sufficient to understand what you were talking about. NOW it is a good answer, i will up vote for the added effort :).

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick that I also use for driving eye-bolts into wood, and that is to use a screw hook or cut eye bolt chucked up in the drill and then hook it through the loop that you want to screw in or turn.

If you have access to a angle grinder or other way to cut a bolt, I suggest using a heavy duty eye bolt and cutting out a part of the loop to make a slot just big enough to fit your jacks eye hole into.

If you'd rather not cut an eye bolt, a heavy J hook can be used, but I have found that you can't get one that is quite as thick as an eye bolt, but that might not be a big deal.

[image: Eye Bolt]

*Imagine this with about a 1/4th of the circle cut away so you can loop it through your jack's eye.*

Turns out I'm not the only one with this idea (of course) - check out [this article](https://todayshomeowner.com/video/how-to-install-screw-hooks-fast/) to see it in action.

Comment: This is the cheap 'n easy solution. "[hook bolt](https://www.google.com/search?q=bolt+hook&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ALeKk00JpAmISw143trOuFrr3iOFZDNczQ:1582577026234&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMxenrhuvnAhXJTd8KHVBeAUEQ_AUoAnoECAwQBA&biw=1842&bih=979)"

Comment: Right, the J-hook/hook bolt (wasn't sure what else to call it) would probably work well for this.  Cutting a full-loop eye hook gives you more control over the opening size.  It just depends how often you're going to be using this.

Comment: I was referring to your answer, not that particular product. There's no need to cut up jack handles for this like others suggest when a $1.59 solution exists (or a free one in the case of any well-stocked leftover hardware bucket).

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this with my scissor jack. I had two of them so I took the hook handle from one of them and cut it off about 5 inches from the hook. Then, using a grinder, I flattened out three equally spaced surfaces on the shaft so the drill chuck would hold fast. You should definitely use a drill with a side handle on it, the torque grab will really twist your arm if using a single grip. You can just use a lag hook if you don't have two jacks.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a great hack on** [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fIVKF7aA8U) Describing the use of an  adapter for a ratchet driver or getting a jack with a bolt head that will accept a socket.

OR , You could buy a new or used scissor jack handle and modify it. You could find a used one at auto junk yard or a thrift store for a couple of dollars. 
[image: scissor jack handle]

Cut the hook end off with a hack saw, **i would cut i long enough that you can reach the jack when it is under the car with out having to put your self under the car.**

Use a grinder or a file to put three flat spots on the shank where it will go into the drill chuck the keep it from spinning in the chuck.

Comment: If you have to reach under the car to attach the jack handle to the jack, you've got the jack in the wrong place. Those scissor jacks (AKA "widow-maker jacks") are designed to lift on the reinforced crimp under the sill panel - the hook should be easily accessible from the side of the car.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you. Not everyone knows that and i felt it was best to state that putting your self under a car while using a *"widow-maker jack"*  is **DANGEROUS**. Thus the name, widow maker.

Comment: The best thing you can do with one of these is chuck it and put a floor jack and jack stands in your trunk. Unfortunately, that's not _really_ practical, so the next best is A) ensure you've got the jack on level, solid ground, B) ensure the jack is properly positioned on the reinforced section of the sill, and C) as soon as the car's off the ground and the tire's off, lay the tire down under the sill right next to the jack - if/when the jack collapses, the car will land partially on the rim instead of fully on you, that way you'll be maimed instead of instantly dead. </OT [mechanics.se]>

Comment: I've only heard the [VW single sided scissor jack](https://www.garagejournal.com/forum/picture.php?albumid=6713&pictureid=93008) called a widowmaker.  Normal scissor jacks aren't that bad.  Of course you shouldn't get _under_ a car using any jack.